# How can i split 'Date' column into 'Date' and 'Time' column?

Tags: pandas, ipython

In the image shown, how can i split 'Date' column into 'Date' and 'Time' column?

[image]'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `whitespace` what is default separator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['4/1/2016 0.00','4/2/2016 0.05']})
print (df)
            Date
0  4/1/2016 0.00
1  4/2/2016 0.05

df[['Date','Time']] = df.Date.str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
       Date  Time
0  4/1/2016  0.00
1  4/2/2016  0.05
```